# How to Remove duplication of words from both sentences using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, uniq

I have a two sentences containing duplicate words, for example, the input data in file `my_text.txt`:

> The Unix and Linux operating system.
> The Unix and Linux system was to create an environment
> that promoted efficient program.

I used this script:

```
while read p
do
echo "$p"|sort -u | uniq
done < my_text.txt
```

But the output is the same content of the input file:

> The Unix and Linux operating system.
> The Unix and Linux system  was to create an environment  that promoted efficient program

How can I remove the duplicate words from both sentences?

Comment: Could you please post more clear samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of question.

Comment: I want to remove any duplicate words in both sentences, in my example, There are 5 repeated words in both sentences ( The, Unix  ,and ,Linux, system ), but I need a script more general for both sentences that contain duplicate words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code would remove repeated *lines;* both `sort` and `uniq` operate on lines, not words. (And even then, the loop is superfluous; if you wanted to do that, your code should be simplified to just `sort -u my_text.txt`.)

The usual fix is to split the input to one word per line; there are some complications with real-world text, but the first basic Unix 101 implementation looks like

```sh
tr ' ' '\n' <my_text.txt | sort -u
```

Of course, this gives you the words in a different order than in the original, and saves the first occurrence of every word.  If you wanted to discard any words which occur more than once, maybe try

```sh
tr ' ' '\n' <my_text.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 == 1 { print $2 }'
```

(If your `tr` doesn't recognize `\n` as newline, maybe try `'\012'`.)

Here is a dead simple two-pass Awk script which hopefully is a little bit more useful. It collects all the words into memory during the first pass over the file, then on the second, removes any words which occurred more than once.

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) ++a[$i]; next }
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (a[$i] > 1) $i="" } 1' my_test.txt my_test.txt
```

This leaves whitespace where words were removed; fixing that should be easy enough with a final `sub()`.

A somewhat more useful program would split off any punctuation, and reduce words to lowercase (so that `Word`, `word`, `Word!`, and `word?` don't count as separate).

Answer (score 3):

Can use this command to remove duplication of words from both sentences :

```
tr ' ' '\n' <my_text.txt | sort | uniq | xargs
```

Answer (score 0):

To output processed lines with preserved order of word occurrences, you can use `awk` to parse and remove the duplicates. This script supports multiple sentences, taking into account words followed by common punctuation marks (`.,;`):

File `remove_duplicates.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    # Store occurences of each word in current line, keyed by the word itself
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sub(/[.,;]/, "", $i)
        seen_words[$i]++
    }
    # Store line, keyed by line number
    lines[$NR]=$0
}
END {
    # Process stored lines
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        split(lines[$i], word, " ")
        output_line=""
        for (j=1; j<=length(word); j++){
            sub(/[.,;]/, "", word[j])
            if (seen_words[word[j]] <= 1) {
                output_line = output_line " " word[j]
            }
        }
        print output_line
    }
}
```

Usage:

```sh
./remove_duplicates.awk < input_text
```

Output:

```
operating
was to create an environment that promoted efficient program
```

Comment: Solutions to homework should probably try to explain what's wrong and only hint at a solution, rather than dump a complex program with little explanation. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

Using awk (GNU awk):

```
 awk '{ 
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { # Loop on each word on each line
          gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"",$i); # Srip out any punctuation
          cnt++; Set a word count variable
          if (!map[$i]) { If there is not an entry for the word in an array, set it with the word as the index and the cnt variable as the value
            map[$i]=cnt 
          } 
         } 
      } 
  END { 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"; # Set the order of the array to value number ascending
        for (i in map) { 
           printf "%s ",i # Print each word with a space
        } 
       }' filename
```

One liner:

```
 awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"",$i);cnt++;if (!map[$i]) { map[$i]=cnt } } } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for (i in map) { printf "%s ",i } }' filename
```

NOTE - This will strip out any punctuation (full stops after words)